# Suggested Unit Testing Approach When Checking for XML Child Nodes

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Unit testing is currently at 60% code coverage on a specific class.  Many of the lines of code that aren't covered by tests look like the following:

```
global class IFXIndividuals {
    global List<IFXIndividual> Individual;
    global string iCount;
    global IFXIndividuals(Dom.XMLNode node) {
        Dom.XMLNode child = node.getChildElement('Individual', null);
        if (child != null) {
            Individual = new List<IFXIndividual>();
            for (Dom.XMLNode ind : node.getChildElements()) {  
                Individual.add(new IFXIndividual(ind));
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

The Individual node of the XML file is as follows:

```
     <Individuals>
      <Individual IndividualType="Applicant">
        <Score>482</Score>
      </Individual>
    </Individuals>
```

The if clause is not covered by my tests.  What would be a suggested testing approach to ensure broader code coverage given the prevalence of this programming pattern?

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example xml and its schema,  But in general you need to create an xml document to parse that has child nodes that are populated.

Comment: Updated to include XML.  Thanks much for your help!

Comment: Its hard to help without more detail. Posting the Unit test method that is attempting to cover this code, how the class is being called and significantly more of the xml will be helpful